# codename one Button click issue

Tags: java, android, codenameone, hybrid-mobile-app

**Hi friends, I am working on Codename one project, which is the demo app based on PSD to APP example below is the splash screen of my application**
[image]
 [! [enter image description here] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7p3u.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7p3u.png)

But whenever I am clicking on the get started button it goes expand like below screenshot and text also move center to left side
[image]

Can anyone help me regarding this.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to style the `Selected` and `Pressed` states of your button UIID in the GUI Builder.

If the Get Started button has **Button** UIID, then style both Pressed and Selected state of **Button** UIID in GUI Builder. See image below:

You could just copy and paste the UIID on both `Selected` and `Pressed` sections.

[image: Button UIID]